# Firefox not creating sslkeylog file after setting SSLKEYLOGFILE variable

Tags: firefox, chromium, environment-variables, ssl, tls

I ran this in the terminal: `export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/home/user/sslkeylog`

After opening regular Firefox, the developer version of Firefox and Chromium, "sslkeylog" was never created, even after visiting a site that uses TLS. I also tried setting the file name to "sslkeylog.log", but that did not help either.

I want to decrypt my web browser traffic using wireshark. 
`

Comment: How did you open FF after having run that terminal command? From terminal or from the graphical environment?

Comment: I opened FF from the graphical environment. After opening it from the terminal, the sslkeylog file was succesffully created. Thank you.

Comment: The conclusion then is that you need to set that variable persistently, e.g. in `~/.profile` which is sourced by the display manager at login.

Comment: Same with Insomnia REST client, opening it via terminal populated the file, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The variable you describe works as intended for me on Firefox 62. Perhaps the browser builds you are using have been built to ignore the variable? From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format:

> [S]tarting with NSS 3.24 (used by Firefox 48 and 49 only), the
>   SSLKEYLOGFILE approach is disabled by default for optimized builds
>   using the Makefile (those using gyp via build.sh are not affected).
>   Distributors can re-enable it at compile time though (using the
>   NSS_ALLOW_SSLKEYLOGFILE=1 make variable) which is done for the
>   official Firefox binaries. (See bug 1188657.) Notably, Debian does not
>   have this option enabled, see Debian bug 842292.

Comment: I only have Firefox 60 and 61.0b5, though it should work on these versions according to the link in your answer. Perhaps it would work if I tried it on Firefox 62.